# Kotlin actors goes to dead lock when capacity is less than number of messages

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to benchmark akka actors with kotlin actors. With some very basic understanding of kotlin, I tried simple test with ping pong and program got stuck. It only progressed to completion only when I made capacity size same as number of messages. With my understanding both actors should continue doing its work and should not depend on capacity.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferred
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.SendChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.actor
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

sealed class Message
class Ping(val replyTo: SendChannel<Message>) : Message()
object Pong : Message()

object Start : Message()

fun CoroutineScope.PingActor() = actor<Message>(capacity = 10) {
    for (msg in channel) { 
        when (msg) {
            is Ping ->
                msg.replyTo.send(Pong)
        }
    }
}

fun CoroutineScope.PongActor(pinger: SendChannel<Message>, count: Int, done: CompletableDeferred<Unit>) =
    actor<Message> (capacity = 10){
        var counter = count 

        for (msg in channel) { 
            when (msg) {
                is Start ->
                    for (i in 1..count) {
                        pinger.send(Ping(this.channel))
                    }

                is Pong -> {
                    counter -= 1
                    if (counter == 0) {
                        done.complete(Unit)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {

    val response = CompletableDeferred<Unit>()
    val pinger = PingActor() 
    val ponger = PongActor(pinger, 100, response) 
    val startTime = System.nanoTime()

    ponger.send(Start)
    response.await()

    println("total time taken is ${System.nanoTime() - startTime}")
    pinger.close() 
    ponger.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It only progressed to completion only when I made capacity size same as number of messages.

You can check that 50 capacity (for both actors) is actually enough. Let's see what happens with 10:

1. `pinger` receives the `Start` message,
2. `pinger` tries to send 100 messages to `ponger`. 10 are sent, 11th blocks until there's more space in the queue.
3. `ponger` handles the messages and sends 10 replies.
4. `pinger` can now send 10 more messages.
5. `ponger` tries to handle the 11th `Ping`, but blocks when sending the reply, because there are 10 messages in `pinger`'s mailbox.

Note that `pinger` doesn't get to ever handling replies because it's still handling the `Start` message.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I do not know the amount of messages ahead of time, then I need to use unlimited capacity.

Comment: That, or change the logic. E.g. with normal ping-pong, you only send first ping immediately, the rest are in reply to pongs. Then you wouldn't run into this problem.